# Decode Stream returning 0 value?

Tags: android, android-bitmap, bitmapfactory

I am trying to download an Image and then display it to my imageView component.

To download I have to use Asyntask and display a progress bar to inform a user. Problem is after going through a loop to get the calculated progress value I get 0 from inputStream.

```
   Log.d("is", "" + inputStream.available()); // ---> will have a value

            byte[] buffer = new byte[contentLenght];
            while ((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {

                counter += read;
                publishProgress(counter);

                outputStream.write(buffer,0,read);
            }
            Log.d("is", "" + inputStream.available()); // -----> will return 0
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream); // bmp will be empty
```

Is there a way to get the calcuated value for progress bar and not get a 0 value at the end in input stream?

I am using Asyntask here.

### Clarification

bmp will have a value and when I do this
`imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);` it will work **ONLY IF** i remove the the loop and just call  `bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);`

**However** if I put a loop before doing this

```
bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
```

the imageView will show nothing

Here is my Full Asynctask Code Including the networking connection

```
   int progressCounter;
        int contentLenght;
        int counter;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

            return ConnectToInternet(params[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aVoid) {
            //Log.d("buff",bmp.toString());
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            progressCounter =(int) (((double) values[0] / contentLenght) * 100);
            progressBar.setProgress(progressCounter);
        }

        boolean ConnectToInternet(String url){
            boolean sucessfull = false;
            URL downloadURL = null;
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            InputStream inputStream = null;


            try {

                downloadURL = new URL(url);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) downloadURL.openConnection();
                inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                contentLenght = connection.getContentLength();
                Log.d("is", "" + inputStream.available());

                int read = -1;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[contentLenght];
                while ((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {

                    counter += read;
                    publishProgress(counter);


                }
                Log.d("is", "" + inputStream.available());
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

                sucessfull = true;

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                connection.disconnect();
                try {

                    inputStream.close();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return  sucessfull;
        }
```

thanks

Comment: is it possible that the url that you're trying to download isn't pointing to the right page? Do some base validation on your side to confirm your assumptions.

Comment: @JoxTraex It is pointing to the right page. If I remove the Loop It will work. Problem is there is no way to tell the user that the app is downloading the Image.

Comment: If the first inputstream has a value.. then why not store the value, or read the bytes in the input stream and keep a counter?

Comment: @JoxTraex I did that too. Still the same. Even If I read the input stream first the last log will be 0. Meaning after reading the IS, my progress bar will always be 0

Comment: Post your full async task code.

Comment: @JoxTraex Ive updated the question. Posted my Async Code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `while` statement is consuming the `inputStream` entirely, so nothing will be left for decoding in `BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream)`.

Try this:

```java
boolean ConnectToInternet(String url){

    // ...

    int read;

    // contentLength may be too big,
    // so read stream in smaller chunks.
    //
    // there's a typo in contentLenght :)
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

    // Object for storing partially downloaded image.
    ByteArrayOutputStream imageBaos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    // Initialize counter.
    counter = 0;

    while ((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {

        counter += read;
        publishProgress(counter);

        // Store downloaded chunk.
        imageBaos.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }

    // Obtain bitmap from downloaded chunks.
    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBaos.toByteArray(), 0, imageBaos.size());

    // ...

}
```

Comment: Working! Thanks :D